# CameraX VideoCapture orientation is inconsistent with ImageCapture orientation

Tags: orientation, video-capture, android-camerax

I find that VideoCapture orientation is inconsistent with ImageCapture in the case where Preview orientation is not the same as Device orientation.

For example: if the Device has portrait orientation and the Preview has landscape orientation, VideoCapture (incorrectly) captures a portrait orientation whereas ImageCapture (correctly) captures a landscape orientation.

The same is true if the Device is landscape and the Preview portrait. The behavior is correct and identical for both ImageCapture and VideoCapture if the Device orientation is the same as the Preview orientation.

Adjusting the value of VideoCapture.setTargetRotation( +1) after bindToLifecycle(), rotates the orientation but not in a helpful way. For example with a portrait Device, and a landscape Preview: the capture (correctly) has a landscape format but the contents (incorrectly) is a crop of portrait oriented contents.

I have a custom Preview which provides a texture to implement Preview.SurfaceProvider. And uses Custom Preview viewer whose configuration depends only on Preview.getResolutionInfo().getCropRect() , Preview.getResolutionInfo().getResolution() , Preview.getResolutionInfo().getRotationDegrees(), and front or back camera.

Other than write my own VideoCapture based on the imageAnalysis use case, what can I do to get the expected behavior?